# How to add programmatically Sharepoint List Filter Wep Part?

Tags: web-part, filter

I try to add Sharepoint List Filter Web Part to page.

I'm not sure if it is  Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SpListFilterWebPart. How to add it to the page and configure?

**Update**

```
        SpListFilterWebPart listfilter = new SpListFilterWebPart();
        listfilter.ListUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/StatisticsFiles";
        listfilter.ValueFieldGuid = fields.GetFieldByInternalName("ID").Id;
        listfilter.DescriptionFieldGuid = fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Title").Id;
        listfilter.ViewGuid = web.Lists.TryGetList("StatisticsFiles").Views["All Items"].ID;

        wpman.AddWebPart(listfilter, "Zone3", 2);
```

wpman.AddWebPart(listfilter, "Zone3", 2); --> here is a mistake as listfilter is Portal.WepControl,  how to add it to the collection

Thank you for help

Comment: Lena, try using `GenericWebPart listfilterWebPart = wpman.CreateWebPart(listfilter);` before `wpman.AddWebPart`

Answer (score 2):

Use the following approach

1.) Create a visual webpart

2.) First add the following on the .ascx page

**Code for .ascx page**

```
<SharePoint:ListViewByQuery runat="server" ID="customlistview" />
```

3.)Add the following code to query your list(assuming you have created the site and web objects)

**Code for .ascx.cs page**

```
 SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("list_name");
 customlistview.List = list;
 SPQuery query = new SPQuery(customlistview.List.DefaultView);
 query.Query = "<Where>....Use your filtering query here.....</Where>";
 customlistview.Query = query;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically if this is an OOTB webpart or a web part which you created, you have to create an instance of it in your code.

Then you have to add this instactance to a webpart collection in a webpart manager on the page.

[Check this link out](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tconte/archive/2007/01/18/programmatically-adding-web-parts-to-a-page.aspx)

Comment: Thank you fo answer. I have updated the question according to your answer. Check it, please.